# Excel VBA: Action logging on label click (like Audit Trail)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wrote a code where every time a label is clicked a line is logged that label XY was clicked. However, I have the problem that when I open UserForm5 8 lines are automatically filled with Label X was clicked, Label Y was licked. But all I want is that I click label, that will be logged. How can I modify the code so that it works?

Attached is my code, this code is in my Module:

```
`Option Explicit

Public Sub LogAction(action As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long


   
    Dim userName As String
    userName = Environ("USERNAME")

    
    Dim timestamp As Date
    timestamp = Now

    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = userName
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = action
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 3).Value = timestamp
End Sub

Sub AssignLabelClickHandlers()

    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In UserForm5.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
            LogAction "label" & ctrl.Caption
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
`
```

And this one on my UserForm5:

```
`UserForm_Initialize()
    AssignLabelClickHandlers
End Sub`
```

Comment: When you show the form, `AssignLabelClickHandlers` calls `LogAction` for each existing label in `UserForm5`. Is this what you want, or you copied the code from somebody who really needed this way of acting? Then, you say "every time a label is clicked a line is logged". Which code calls `LogAction` and how? Please, edit your question and place the respective code, too.

Comment: this is my complete code, and the question is how I can edit this so that when I click label X in my UserForm5 a line is made in the worksheet with label X was clicked. I have more than 40 labels in this userform5.

Comment: at the moment in excel lines are created as soon as i open userform5 with 40 lines if i have 40 labels with label X was clicked but i don't want that but the line should be generated when label is clicked with corresponding label X was clicked.

Comment: So, you need a piece of code to log what is to be logged when you execute click on one of the existing labels. Would this be a correct understanding? If so, do you know how to insert a class module? In order to assign the `Click`  event of each label, you need wrapper to do it when the user form is open. It can be written in a class module. Theoretically, it is not a big deal. You can insert a class module in the same way you insert a standard one. Do you understand what I mean? I will do it if you confirm that you are familiar with such an issue...

Comment: Actually i know class module but i dont know how to creat such a thing. I would be happy if you can write the code for me

Comment: OK, I am not at home now. I will do it after some hours, when I will be at home. In the evening. Now, my local time is 12:43...

Comment: Please, test the solution I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please, delete your existing procedure `LogAction` and the actual content of `UserForm_Initialize` event
2. Please, insert a class module and name it "ClassLabelsEvents", then copy the next code inside its code module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents myLabel As MSForms.Label

Private Sub myLabel_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    
    lastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1

    'It is faster to place all three necessary values at once, from an array:
    ws.cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(, 3).value = Array(Environ("USERNAME"), myLabel.Caption, Now)
End Sub
```

3. Declare the next variable on top of the user form code modulel (in the declarations area):

```
Option Explicit

Private lblClass() As New ClassLabelsEvents
```

If there are already other declared variables in that area, just place another code line containing the above declaration.
4. Copy the next code in the `UserForm_Initialize` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control, k As Long

  ReDim lblClass(Me.Controls.count) 'redim the array to be able to keep the whole number of existing controls

  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 'iterate between the user form controls:
      If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then 'for label controls type only:
        Set lblClass(k).myLabel = ctrl: k = k + 1 'add them in the class array
      End If
  Next

  ReDim Preserve lblClass(k - 1) ' keep only loaded label controls in the array
End Sub
```

Now, activate "Tabelle1" sheet (not necessary for the code to run, only to see the logging result as it is done) and play with clicking labels...

I tried commenting all lines which could not be understood. If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Please, send some feedback after testing the above suggested solution.